# ASP.NET invoke event on worker thread, need to update UI element in handler

Tags: c#, asp.net, multithreading

I'm currently writing a little background worker that invokes a "WorkerFinished" event when the thread is done executing. The problem is though, that I obviously cannot update any UI elements in the handler of this event. I need to enable some buttons in the main ASP page after the thread is done.

So, I know I cannot do this straight forward like so, but I haven't got a slightest clue on exactly how to work around this.

Here is the relevant code:

```
public void Start(Dictionary<string, object> args)
{
   m_thread = new Thread(() =>
        {
            m_progress = 0;
            DoWork.Invoke(ref m_progress, ref m_result, args);
            m_progress= 100;

            m_isDone= true;
            if( FinishedWork != null )
                 FinishedWork.Invoke(ref m_result, args); // Here goes
        });
        m_thread .Name = m_name;
        m_thread .IsBackground = true;
        m_thread .Start();
}
```

So, from this, I subscripe to the **FinishedWork** event on a ASP Page, where I need to enable a "Start" button again.

So, is there a way for me to make sure this invocation happens on the UI thread?

Thanks, Oyvind.

Comment: ASP.Net doesn't have a UI thread.  You need to understand how HTTP works.  Instead, use Signalr.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't.  By the time you finish the background task the response to the client has already been sent.  It's gone.  If you try to send any information to the client that is not in response to a particular request, or for a request that they have already received a response for, then their firewall is sure to block that transmission.  It's simply contrary to the standard web model. The client makes a request, the server sends a response, and that's it.

That model not designed for two way communication between the client and the server in which the server can send data to the client at any time.

Models that *do* support this two way communication exist, but not all clients will support it.

Another option is to have the client constantly polling the server (presumably asynchronously) constantly asking it, "Are you done yet?", "Are you done yet?", "Are you done yet?"  The general model here is that the asynchronous task will store some information pertaining to it's progress in a form of global state accessible to future requests (i.e. a database, session, etc.) and the frequent polling requests from the client will look at that state.  An example of this model can be seen [here](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/CSASPNETBackgroundWorker-dda8d7b6/view/SourceCode).  Note that this is very resource intensive on the network to be constantly polling the server for updates, so be careful how you use this pattern.

Comment: Thank you for the clarifying answer. Would you support the suggestion of doing it by updating the session with the progress instead, and then fire events when the progress iterator hits certain values?

I do however, want to run a worker function async, so that the user can browse the site while it's loading, without using any jQuery ajax requests

Comment: @OyvindAndersson And you can do that, but the only way for the client to "see" those progress values it will need to make a request to the server.  This can either be an AJAX request which you're periodically sending on the current page, or as the result of the client going to new pages and generating a full page load.  You won't be able to update the client UI without some sort of client request though.